# How to display a images for a directory using Next.js and Wild Apricot API

Tags: next.js

I am attempting to build a directory using Next.js and Wild Apricot API for a client's association that displays company logos next to the contact info. They have >500 contacts and have a field they have been using to upload logos already. I obviously do not want to expose the client's API key so I am using it on the server side, and while my code seems to return image blobs on the backend for the first 120, it then hits the WA call limit and cuts me off. Additionally I have not been able to get the blobs to pass to my client side which then maps through the results to display them.

This is the last step needed to ship this project out and I have been stuck on it for awhile. Does anyone have suggestions on how to handle this?

```
const getAccounts = (token) => {
        axios
            .get(`https://api.wildapricot.com/v2.2/accounts/[ACCOUNT_NUMBER]/contacts?%24async=false&%24filter=Status%20eq%20'Active'`, {
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'MySampleApplication/0.1',
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },

            })
            .then(async (response) => {
                try {
                    const accounts = response.data;

                    // Collect all image URLs that need to be fetched
                    const imageUrlsToFetch = accounts.Contacts
                        .filter(contact => contact.FieldValues[49]?.Value !== '')
                        .map(contact => contact.FieldValues[49].Value.Url);

                    // Fetch all image blobs concurrently
                    const imageBlobs = await Promise.all(imageUrlsToFetch.map(async (imageUrl) => {
                        try {
                            const response = await fetch(`${imageUrl}?%24async=false&asBase64=true`, {
                                headers: {
                                    'User-Agent': 'MySampleApplication/0.1',
                                    Accept: 'application/json',
                                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                                },
                            });
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                throw new Error(`Failed to fetch image blob: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
                            }
                            return await response.json(); // Assuming the blob data is JSON-encoded
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error('Error fetching image blob:', error);
                            return null; // Handle errors gracefully
                        }
                    }));

                    // Assign image blobs to respective contacts
                    accounts.Contacts.forEach((contact, index) => {
                        if (contact.FieldValues[49]?.Value !== '') {
                            // Assuming the image blob is stored in 'Image' property
                            contact.FieldValues[49].Image = imageBlobs[index];
                            console.log(contact.FieldValues[49].Image);
                        }
                    });

                    res.status(200).send(accounts);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error processing response:', error);
                    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching account data:', error);
                res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
            });
    };
```